# jQuery Redirect using URL from variable

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a WordPress site which I am calling a URL from a custom field using the following

```
<?php $redirect_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 're_url', true);
```

I am also using TinyBox2 to display this URL in a popup box, using the callback function I have set it to run a function in the footer that redirects to, for now, www.google.com

```
TinyBox
-------
<div class="redirect" onclick="TINY.box.show({html:'Your website is : <br /><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 're_url', true); ?>',animate:true,close:true,mask:false,boxid:'success',openjs:function(){openJS()}})"></li>

Footer
------
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openJS(){setTimeout("top.location.href = '$redirect_url'",5000);}
</script<
```

This isnt working as I want it to, can anybody explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write php variable, so that javascript can pick it up!!

```
function openJS(){setTimeout("top.location.href = '<?php echo $redirect_url; ?>'",5000);}
```

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I was missing the obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

Set timeout accepts a function, not a string.

EDIT: Here's some (untested) code. This should get you going in the right direction, I hope.

```
function openJS(){
   window.setTimeout(function(){
      window.location = "<?php echo $URL ?>";
   }, 5000);
}
```